# How to subset the dataframe byusing for loop and if condition in r

Tags: r

"I have 150 rows and 7 columns, i have to subset the female data using for loop and if statement in R, i have tried followig code am getting only one row. please help him out."

```
da_M<-data.frame()
da_F<-data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(da)){
  if (da$Gender[i]=="Female")
    da_F=da[i,]
  else
    da_M=da[i,]
}
```

Comment: why do you _have to_ use a for loop and if statement?  Also, show a sample of your data.

Comment: I got it, i have to ue rbind function for (i in 1:nrow(da)){
  if (da$Gender[i]=="Female")
    da_F=rbind(da_F,da[i,])
  else
    da_M=rbind(da_M,da[i,])
}

Comment: `split(da, da$Gender)` will give you a list of the dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Using vectorization, which is a lot faster than a for-loop:

```
da_F <- da[which(da$Gender=="Female"),]
da_M <- da[which(da$Gender!="Female"),]
```

Comment: Thanks Phann and Zico

Answer (score 0):

```
## Sample data I created for convenience

da <- data.frame(Gender = c("male","Female","male","Female"), val = c(1,2,3,4))
da_M<-data.frame()
da_F<-data.frame()

## Your way

for (i in 1:nrow(da)){

  if (da$Gender[i]=="Female")

    da_F <- rbind(da_F, da[i, ])
  else

    da_M <- rbind(da_M, da[i, ])
}

## Alternative Way

da_M <- da[da$Gender == "male", ]
da_F <- da[da$Gender == "Female", ]
```